# Trying to generate incremental numbers in a function with foreach

Tags: php

This function creates `<li>` tags and im trying to give each `li` tag a unique CSS class name,
I've tried to create a `for` loop to generate numbers but this is producing the number 7 rather than counting down to the number 7 in `<li>` tag.

any help greatly appreciated!

```
function the_meta() {

if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
    echo "<ul class='post-meta'>\n";

 //tried to add this counter here to generate incremental numbers in the foreach loop
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) { } 

    foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
        $keyt = trim($key);
        if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
            continue;
        $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
        $value = implode($values,', ');


        echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li class='$i'><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);

    }


    echo "</ul>\n";
}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) { }
```

Will just increase $i until it get to 6, 
So when you're getting to the "main loop" the variable `$i` will have the same value.
Why having another loop to count?

You can implement the counter inside your current loop:

```
$i = 1; //Before the loop , set a starting value.
    foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
        $keyt = trim($key);
        if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
            continue;
        $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
        $value = implode($values,', ');


        echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li class='$i'><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);
$i++; //Increase by one!!
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That initial for loop wasn't really doing anything (as you noted), just initialize a variable at 0, then print and increment it every time you use it:

```
function the_meta() {

if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
echo "<ul class='post-meta'>\n";
$i=0;
foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
    $keyt = trim($key);
    if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
        continue;
    $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
    $value = implode($values,', ');


    echo apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li class='".$i++."'><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);

}


echo "</ul>\n";
}
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to increase the counter before the end of the loop `$i++`

Comment: already took care of that, i did it inline in the echo statement

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop just iterates doing nothing. You have to use:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
   // ...
   $i++;
}
```